# Will it be possible for Apple to enable active noise cancelling on regular Airpods?

Tags: headphones, noise-cancelling

I wonder if Apple is able to enable active noise cancelling on regular Airpods (like Airpods 1st/2nd generation but not the Pro one). Maybe over a firmware update? I will still be very happy even if it is not as good as Airpods Pro does.

edit: I mean is it possible on hardware.

Comment: This question can only be answered by Apple.

Comment: @gronostaj - it's actually answerable - the older ones simply don't have the hardware to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Noise cancelling requires hardware support. It's done using extra tiny microphones on the *outside* of the Airpods as well as an internally-facing mic.
No extra mics, no noise cancelling.

Comment: This is correct. Software can do only so much and would cause a huge dip in battery performance, something Apple will definitely not do.